# Trouble passing data between scenes when I segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, segue

I've done tutorials where I pass data through scenes with the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method, but right now when I try to use the passed data, it's null. I'm using a navigation controller as well.

here's the .h -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "TalkChatTableViewController.h"

@interface CreateChatTableViewController : UIViewController 

@end
```

here's the .m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"idSegueMyChatsToChat"]){
             TalkChatTableViewController *tctvc = [segue destinationViewController];
             tctvc.chatObjectId = @"test";
             NSLog(@"%@", tctvc.chatObjectId);
             //succesfully logs out test
          }
}
```

When I log in the above method, it comes out fine. But then when I go to my `TalkChatTableViewController` class it doesn't log out in `viewDidLoad`; it's null.

The header to that looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TalkChatTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic) NSString * chatObjectId;
@end
```

and then finally the .m -

```
#import "TalkChatTableViewController.h"

@implementation TalkChatTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.chatObjectId);
   // logs null
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you initializing self.chatObjectId?

Comment: Wouldn't it be initializing in the prepareForSegue method?

Comment: How did you set up your segue between the two viewControllers and where did you call -performSegueWithIdentifier:?

Answer (score 0):

```
TalkChatTableViewController * tctvc = (TalkChatTableViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
```

This is what winded up working.